# Конструкция с НЕ: слитно или раздельно?

Tags: частица-не

Списание с балансового учета кредиторской задолженность по суммам произведенных подотчетным лицом расходов, (не)востребованным подотчетными лицами.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Частица НЕ пишется раздельно с причастием при наличии зависимого слова:

**не востребованный (кем?) подотчетными лицами.**

Пример:

Так и собралась потихоньку коллекция авторов, **не востребованных официальными собраниями** советского времени. [Парк культуры (1997) // 
«Столица», 1997.07.15]

Возможное **редактирование** предложения:

Списание с балансового учета кредиторской задолженности по суммам произведенных подотчетным лицом расходов, **не востребованных подотчетными лицами.**